# EPiServer vs ASP.NET membership

Tags: asp.net, episerver

Is there any difference on creating users and roles using the EPiServer membership API and the ASP.NET membership API?

I mean, is it the same to do this:

Membership.CreateUser()

and this?

multiplexingMembershipProvider.CreateUser()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have implemented or configured a .net membership provider it would be the same thing since EPiServer Membership and Role management rely on the standard .net providers.

Comment: so is it the same to use Membership.CreateUser() and multiplexingMembershipProvider.CreateUser() ?

Comment: Multiplexing is a combination of all providers, if you use multiplexing it will create the user in the first provider where it is allowed to create users